# Varieties of dimension $n$ with an $n$-parameter family of lines

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a projective variety of dimension $n$ with an $n$-parameter family of lines. Is $X\cong \mathbb{P}^n$? I know this is true for $n=2$, but I'm curious about generalizations.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: The space of lines in $\mathbf P^n$ is the Grassmannian $G(2,n+1)$, which has dimension $2(n-1)$. So for $n>2$ the space of lines has dimension strictly greater than $n$. Does your question mean "a family of lines of dimension at least $n$?"

Comment: By the way, this MO question is relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/147229/lines-on-fano-complete-intersections

Answer (score 1):

There are other examples, for example hypersurfaces $X_d\subset \mathbb{P}^{n+1}$ of dimension $n$ and low degree $d$ relative to $n$.

It suffices to show we can find $d$ so there is a 1-parameter family of lines through any point $p\in X_d$. The lines through $p$ in $\mathbb{P}^{n+1}$ are parameterized by a $\mathbb{P}^{n}$. You can show (by expanding out the equation defining $X$ around $p$) that the family of lines through $p$ in $X_d$ is dimension at least $n-d$.

Therefore, it suffices to have $d\leq n-1$.

More generally, if $L\subset X\subset \mathbb{P}^N$ and the canonical divisor $K_X$ restricts to something of high enough degree on $L$ (I think $\geq 3$), then we can wiggle the line in $X$ enough to get an $n$-dimensional family. Somebody who knows more about such varieties (and this story) should tell me more.